# Where to and how to install a logging infrastructure for a python app

Tags: python, logging

I've written a Python application, that I install on the required machines using distribute.

I've now added some minimal logging infrastructure by creating a FileHandler:

```
logging.FileHandler('/var/log/something.log')
```

The issue is, that not on all machines I can write to /var/log by default. Also when running my tests on the continuous integration server, it tries to access /var/log/something.log.

How can I avoid hardcoding a log location ? How do you handle the location of log files gracefully ?

Comment: This is a very broad and open-ended question, really. You can make the path a variable of course, but the question then is where to place the log files, what the logic would be to determine where to log and if to log, etc. Does your application have configuration, or accept command line switches?

Comment: yes it has a configuration file

Comment: Then why not allow the logging to be configured through that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid this; the names have to be written somehwere. But you can put all your configuration data in one file, or one folder, and hardcode *its* relative location.

The other option is get it as a user input. I believe it's not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other ideas.

Set the logging information in the shell as a variable, read this in your configuration file. An extra advantage of this approach is that you don't expose sensitive information (like encryption or remote keys) in your files.  You could combine the setting of the environment variables by your deployment scripts (an installer, for example, or via puppet/chef).

If your end clients have access to the Internet, an external logger like [loggly](http://loggly.com/) would also work. If access is restricted, you can [create your own central logger](http://graylog2.org/); and have your application log to the system log facility. If your logging needs are modest - you can use [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry); which is primarily for error logging but can be used for any other logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a syslog logger over UDP. You don't need special permissions to send UDP packets, and you can send them to the localhost (if it has a udp listener), or to a remote host.

If you're unfamiliar with syslog, check out the free version of syslog-ng, it's got all sorts of useful doodads to pimp out your logging.

Locally stored log files are difficult to manage, can fill up partitions, etc.. If everything goes to a centralized server that you can monitor and cleanup easily - or if it fills up or dies, no biggie. Syslog messages just get sent into UDP-bitbucket until your log server accepts messages again. (Obviously, for something like financial transactions, you'd want something a little more resillient)

But for logging errors and the usual 'everything's ok alarms', syslog is great, supported intrinsically by python stdlib, and supported on every operating system. (I forget if windows has native syslog support, but there's definitely opensource syslog servers for windows)